# How to disable creation of SQUIRREL_GET_ERROR_OFFSET in Squirrel SQL?

Tags: squirrel-sql

Squirrel SQL creates a function on the oracle database called SQUIRREL_GET_ERROR_OFFSET. This was questioned by our DBAs. I found an explanation on what it is, but not how to turn off its creation. I am using Squirrel SQL version 3.5.3.

> It is a function that the Oracle plugin creates and uses to position
>   the cursor at the statement token where a syntax error occurred. It
>   has the following definition and is created when an Oracle session is
>   connected while the Oracle plugin is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try unchecking "Show Syntax Error Offset in SQL Editor" in File / Global Preferences / Oracle.